# onclick works after scroll

Tags: java, android, adapter, onclicklistener

I created a very simple authentication for click on the adapter.
for example when user clicks on an item, the "phone" will be sent to the database and when if confirmed, Toast shows "Yes".
otherwise Toast will show "No!".

But when app runs at first when you click on an item (if the method responds "ok") Toasts No!.
But after a some scroll on the page and click on item again, Toast shows Yes.
Actually first when app runs, response doesn't show any value
But after page scroll, It will show the value.

I completely confused. Thanks for help.

a part of my adapter

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull viewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
Model modelPost = this.modelPost.get(i);

viewHolder.cardView.setOnClickListener(v -> {

            check();

            if (access == null) {

                Toast.makeText(context, "No!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {

                Toast.makeText(context, "Yes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

My method at the bottom of the page

```
private void check() {

        String url = "https://example.com/index.php";
        Response.Listener<String> listener = response -> {
            if (response.trim().equals("ok")) {
                access = "1";
            }
        };
        Response.ErrorListener errorListener = error -> Toast.makeText(context, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, listener, errorListener) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> map = new Hashtable<>();
                map.put("User", phone);
                return map;
            }
        };
        MySingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(request);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's Because initially, `access` is null when you call `check()` after response returns ok `access` is set to "1". So when you click again on card view it will display Yes instead of No.

Scrolling behavior has nothing to do with it.

You can just put your Toast messages in the response check itself

```
private void check() {

        String url = "https://example.com/index.php";
        Response.Listener<String> listener = response -> {
             if (response.trim().equals("ok")) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "No!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             } else {
               Toast.makeText(context, "Yes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
        };
        Response.ErrorListener errorListener = error -> Toast.makeText(context, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, listener, errorListener) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> map = new Hashtable<>();
                map.put("User", phone);
                return map;
            }
        };
        MySingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(request);

    }
```

Comment: You should check wheather the backed  returning proper response or not I recommed you to put the log statement and check response

Answer (score 0):

First time when you click on the item toast shows no because value of access variable is null on that time why it is null because in the method check response listener is doing work in background and this bloew code executes before response came later when you again click it print yes because on that time value of access variable is not null. You have to make arrangement in the code to work it properly you can check the value of access variable inside listener and check log.

```
if (access == null) {
 Toast.makeText(context, "No!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else {
   Toast.makeText(context, "Yes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
```